C# WPF dependent value is not updating
I'm working on a C# .NET 6.0 project with WPF, and I have the following scenario:
I have two textboxes in my WPF application:
<StackPanel>
    <Label>Fee Percentage:</Label>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ContractExtension.FeesPercentage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel>
    <Label>Amount in $</Label>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding FeesAmount, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
</StackPanel>

The value of the second text box depends on the value of the first one:
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private ContractExtension contractExtension;

    public ContractExtension ContractExtension
    {
        get { return contractExtension; }
        set
        {
            contractExtension = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ContractExtension));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FeesAmount));
        }
    }

    public decimal FeesAmount
    {
        get
        {
            decimal feesAmount = Toolbox.GetContractGivenValue(contract, false) * ContractExtension.FeesPercentage / 100;
            return feesAmount;
        }
    }
}

public abstract class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Attributes
    private Window parentWindow;
    #endregion Attributes

    #region Properties
    public Window ParentWindow
    {
        get
        {
            return parentWindow;
        }
        set
        {
            parentWindow = value;
            SetParentWindow(value);
        }
    }

    public abstract void SetParentWindow(Window parentWindow);
    public SearchBoxViewModel SearchBoxViewModel { get; }
    #endregion Properties

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    public abstract void ResetData();

    protected static ExceptionManager exceptionManager;

    public BaseViewModel()
    {
        exceptionManager = new ExceptionManager();
        SearchBoxViewModel = new SearchBoxViewModel();
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public void RefreshProperty(string propertyName)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }
}

However, when I modify the value of FeesPercentage, FeesAmount doesn't update in the interface. ContractExtension is an entity model, and Toolbox.GetContractGivenValue is a utility method used to calculate FeesAmount.
Things I've checked:

Ensuring that ContractExtension implements INotifyPropertyChanged
Verifying that the DataContext is correctly set
Checking that the setter of ContractExtension is called when FeesPercentage changes

Is there anything else I should check or modify in my code to make FeesAmount update properly in the interface when FeesPercentage changes?
What I don't understand is that everywhere else in my application this is the way I did it and it worked, but it doesn't work here... I debugged the ContractExtension get,set it enters the set on the initialisation, but whenever I edit the value of FeesPercentage in the textbox, it doesn't trigger the set of ContractExtension and therefore doesn't do OnPropertyChanged(FeesAmount).

Why is it ContractExtension.FeesPercentage but only FeesAmount shouldn't it be ContractExtension.FeesAmount ?!?

but whenever I edit the value of FeesPercentage in the textbox, it doesn't trigger the set of ContractExtension why should this be the case? do you believe it should happend automagically?

"FeesAmount" will play off "FeesPercentage", impying FeesPercentage requires a PropertyChanged handler (which then calls the prop change on "FeesAmount"), of which there is no evidence ("property changing" the "parent" does nothing). One also questions the use of a "read only" TextBox when a TextBlock would suffice. Lastly, you could confirm that "feesamount" in the getter actually has a value via a breakpoint or a debug write.

It seems you would need to do this:
public ContractExtension ContractExtension
{
    get { return contractExtension; }
    set
    {
        //remove event listener from previous instance
        if (contractExtension is not null)
            contractExtension.PropertyChanged -= ContractExtension_OnPropertyChanged;

        contractExtension = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ContractExtension));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FeesAmount));

        //listen to the propertychanged event of your contractExtension
        contractExtension.PropertyChanged += ContractExtension_OnPropertyChanged;
    }
}

private void ContractExtension_OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
     //trigger FeesAmount if FeesPercentage changes
     if (args.PropertyName == nameof(ContractExtension.FeesPercentage))
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FeesAmount));
}

